# Ampscript - Inputting Variable inside SET Statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, dynamic-content, variable

So I have a sendable data extension for an email, for which  I'm wanting to input a Subject with dynamic content. For example IF Customer_Region is US then SET Subject = "Hi @First_Name, how are the states?"

I've got the First_Name declared in the block in the top of the email, and have @Subject in the Subject line. However, whenever I test this, it shows Hi @First_Name, are the states? instead of the person's actual first name.

Am I missing something here? Can you put a dynamic variable from a data extension inside a SET statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @First_Name variable's being used inside quotations, so it interpreted as a string and not being substituted. Build your Subject variable using Concat().

**Email Body**

```
%%[
    VAR @Subject
    SET @First_Name = AttributeValue('MyFirstNameFieldFromSendableDE')
    IF Customer_Region == 'US' THEN
        SET @Subject = CONCAT('Hi ',@First_Name,', how are The States?')
    ELSE
        SET @Subject = CONCAT('Hi ',@First_Name,', Lucky You!')
    ENDIF
]%%
```

**Subject**

```
%%=v(@Subject)=%%
```